# Windows PowerShell Current Code Page Keep Changing

Tags: powershell

my Windows 10 PowerShell's **current code page** keeps changing back to `950 (ANSI/OEM - Traditional Chinese Big5)`.

I have tried "**chcp 437**" command on PowerShell and it did set back to default US code page for the current PowerShell window but once I reopen the PowerShell, it returns back to 950.

I also tried to change the system local in the **Administrative Region Language for non-Unicode programs** to English (United States), it didn't change anything for PowerShell.

The Command Prompt works fine without any problems. See attached screenshot, the Command Prompt and PowerShell now have different current code page settings. Is there anyway to change the PowerShell current code page permanently? Or is it a bug that only happens in PowerShell?

[image]

Comment: You could put the command `chcp 437 | Out-Null` in your PowerShell profile, which you can edit using `notepad $profile`.
Another way of doing it is by editing the shortcut to PowerShell (or ISE) by adding the following to the end of the "Target" command line: `-NoExit -Command "chcp 1252"`

Comment: These methods may work but they are not the best way to do. I wish there is a better/proper way to do instead of forcing it to change. I guess I have to use Command Prompt instead of PowerShell.